# Is there a way to receive ALL the files in a computer?

Tags: python

Is there a way to list and receive ALL but ALL the files in the C: drive in a computer with Python ?

Comment: Yes there is. Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: @wwii Hey, I just asked  a question, there is nothing more to explain...

Comment: @wwii But I didn't asked like this.

Comment: @wwii This isn't asking "can someone help me". It's asking how to do a specific thing.

Comment: @khelwood All the question in SO is 'can someone help me' or how to do a specific thing.

Comment: @MasterBootRecord I was not criticising your question. I was defending it.

Comment: Not my downvote by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import os

# iterate over each file:
for file in os.walk('C:\\'):
    print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

for result in os.walk('path_to_directory'):
  print(result)
```

Comment: This will require a little more to print only the files. Also some explanations (and even a link) could be useful here